# jquery UI dialog multiple instances when pressed enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

There are similar questions but they could not help me solve this.

When the dialog opens and I press enter, I want this to be equivalent to closing the dialog.

I have written the following but it does not work. Instead, at every ENTER, the focus stays on the element that triggers the opening of the dialog, giving rise to multiple instances.

Thanks

```
var $dialogError = $('<div id="dialogError"></div>').html(vGraph.getLastErrorMsg()).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    open: function() {
        $("#dialogError").keydown(function(e) {
            alert("enter");
            if (e.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.ENTER) {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        });
    },
    title: 'Error'
});
$dialogError.dialog('open');​
```

Comment: Instead of `$("#dialogError").keydown(function(e) {` how about `$("body").keydown(function(e) {`?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe set the focus to the dialogError element using `$('#dialogError').focus();` after opening the dialog, that way the focus is no longer on the element that opened the dialog, and it will capture the enter key.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('keypress', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.ENTER) {
        $('#dialogError').dialog('close');    
    }
});​
```

This will work regardless of whether the dialog has focus or not which is probably what you want.  This code will execute when the dialog is not open, but running `$('#dialogError').dialog('close');` will have no adverse effects.

**Example** - http://jsfiddle.net/tj_vantoll/x32zC/1

Answer (score 0):

try returning `false` from the `keydown` handler:

`open: function() {
    $("#dialogError").keydown(function(e) {
        alert("enter");
        if (e.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.ENTER) {
            $(this).dialog("close"); 
            return false;
        }
    });
},`